# rails many to many and one to many ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `Item` and `User`. An `Item` is created and owned by a `User`. But an `Item` also has users other than its owner.

It seems like I need a many to many relationship between items and users. But in addition, I also need a one to many ownership relation of a user who owns many items.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I've set up my migrations like so.

A table to hold the many connections between users and items.

```
create_table :items_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.column :item_id, :integer
  t.column :user_id, :integer
end
```

As well as the ownership of an `Item` by a `User`.

```
add_reference :items, :user, index: true
add_foreign_key :items, :users
```

This means I can access the owner of an `Item` with `item.user_id`. I can also access the many to many relationship of users and items with `item.users` and `user.items`.

I do not know how to access the items that a `User` owns through a `User` object. The items that a `User` owns should be different from the ones in the many to many relationship of `user.items`.

I feel like I'm structuring everything wrong. I'm extremely new to rails and I'm quite confused. What is the proper way to accomplish this in rails?

Comment: In real-world terms, what is the other users relationship for? Reason is you could structure it differently depending on the scenario: either maintain two separate relationships to the same model, or have one many-to-many relationship with the join table describing the "role" of that user for that particular item (so you'd have a "creator" role, and whatever else you need). You could then define different `has_many` relationships in the models which filter depending on that role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :items, through: :user_items

  has_many :owned_items, through: :user_items, source: item, where: -> {
    user_items: {owned: true}
  }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_items
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  scope :owned, -> {
    where(owned: true)
  }
end

create_table :user_items |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :item
  t.boolean :owned, null: false, default: false
end
```

Comment: @ilan_berci I'm slightly confused with how the ````scope :owned, -> { where(owned: true )}```` works. Thanks for the response. I think this method makes the most sense.

Comment: You don't have to use the scope if you don't want to.  I just wanted to illustrate that if your associative table contains that attribute, rails will handle most of the details

Comment: @ilan_berci The scope makes perfect sense after a bit of reading. The last thing to understand is the ````source: item do```` I understand the merge is meant to find the intersection of all owned user items and what? I'm not entirely sure what ````item```` is meant to reference. Thanks again Ilan!

Comment: @jpittis You're joining to another table through a join table, but Rails can't infer from the name of the `has_many` relationship what model you're trying to load, so `source` essentially makes that explicit. Also, if you want as well, an alternative to the `merge` is to simply place the condition in the `has_many` directly, like so: `has_many :owned_items, -> {where(owned: true)}, through:....`. I'm not sure what the difference in the query would be between the two methods though.

Comment: I had trouble making the one part of your code work. After some head banging, the following seems to work.

````has_many :owned_items, -> { where user_items: { owned: true } }, through: :user_items, source: :item````

Comment: thank you jpittis, I usually have to play around to get things to work as well.. I will update with your find

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that with a many-to-many association from User and Item you can resolve, but if you want a clearer solution you have to "traslate" your idea in the data model (oob way).

You tell us: Item have an owner, that is an user, and have many users. So you need an Owner model and build a [has_one :throught association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

For example, for Item model you can set:

```
>has_many :users 
>has_one :user throught :owners
>has_one :owner
```

For User model you can set:

```
>has_many :items
>belongs_to :owner
```

For Owner model you can set:

```
>has_one :user
>belongs_to :item
```

Comment: Users and "owners" / "creators" are the same class in the OPs scenario, the only difference is the relationship between items and users. The "owner" / "creator" is more a description of the relationship, rather than an entirely different domain model on its own.

Comment: @PaulRichter i'm with you about thinking deeper about what are the real relationships. But in the simple situation described by jpittis i think that focusing about "special" users as "creator/owner" is a big "small" step. Well, i'm really not a big expert, only my 2cents hoping it can helps :)

Comment: Would you think it better to have a Owner class that might end up having zero logic? Or instead should I use the technique below where I create a UserItem that specifies if the relationship is an owner or not. I'm leaning toward the one below. Thanks guys.

Comment: @jpittis The `UserItem` join model is pretty much exactly what I was talking about in my comment on the question, except that version simply has a more explicit relationship discriminator, rather than a roles-based solution. A roles-based solution would be better if your system needed to define more details about each kind of user-item relationship, but its perfectly fine if you just need an owner-regular guy relationship. Plus, an Owner is merely a User that has the 'owner property' for that item, which can best be cleanly expressed on the join model itself.